# Changing a form based on Dropdown Selection in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I have the below code which is designed to show the form elements in the div "privileged" when a User ID not equal to the current logged in User ID is selected.

In summary, I have tried to code this so that when a user that is not the user logged in is selected, the inputs "comment" and "duration" inside the div "privileged" are shown, if the User selects themselves, then this is hidden.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, I have tried using an `alert` in the JavaScript and this is never shown, so I don't think the JavaScript is being called at all.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>   
    $(document(function () {
        $('#select').on('change', function() {
            if( this.value === <?php auth()->user()->id ?>) $('.#privileged').hide();
        });
    });
</script>

@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{url('requests') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="employee">Employee: </label>
        <select name="employee" id="employee">
            <?php $users = DB::table('users')->get() ?>
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <option value="{{$user->id}}" >{{$user->first_name}} {{$user->second_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="start_date">Start Date (Inclusive): </label>
        <input type="date" name="start_date" /> <br>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="end_date">End Date (Inclusive): </label>
        <input type="date" name="end_date" /> <br>
    </div>

    <div class="privileged">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="duration">Number of Days: </label>
            <input type="number" step= "0.01" name="duration" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Comment: </label>
            <input type="text" name="comment" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <input type="submit"  class="btn" />
    </div>
</form>
                        
@endsection
```

Comment: Hi , this `$('#select')` should be `$('#example')`and this `$('.#privileged')`should be `$('.privileged')`

Comment: @Swati Thank you for your help. I gave this a try, but there is still no result.

Comment: are you seeing any error inside browser console ? Also , put this `<?php auth()->user()->id ?>` around quoted `''`.

Comment: @Swati I've given the `''` a try, but they don't seem to have made a difference. Had a check in the browser console and seeing on "Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed." but this is for a separate code module, could this be having an impact?

Comment: I am not sure see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49dnazLg/) . You have error here as well `$(document(function () {..`

Answer (score 0):

try calling javascript inside @section

Comment: I gave this a try, but placing inside of the @section stops anything else within the section from showing on the screen.